# PHP facebook application

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

I'm starting out to learn how to build a Facebook application, but I've run in to some problems. I can't seem to find a simple tutorial on how to authenticate and ask for permissions from the user. The app itself is in php and consists of a simple quiz. I'm using the php sdk 3.0, but in the example file you have to login before you are asked to allow permissions. I just want the user to be redirected to the permissions prompt when the app is loaded.

So, to be more specific, I need som sort of basic script that authenticates and ask the user for permissions. I'm using the php sdk, but if there is a better way please feel free to suggest this.

Comment: "but in the example file you have to login before you are asked to allow permissions." - logging into application = asking for permissions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189151/asking-for-permission-using-new-php-sdk

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer, but on all the apps I ever installed I was asked permissions directly without logging in. And what exactly am I logging in to? I'm allready logged in to Facebook.

Comment: Thank you @HenrikPeinar, it's possibly this I need help with. I ran the script and was lead to the permissions prompt at once. But when I accepted I was redirected from Facebook to the callback url (where my app is hosted). Do you know why this is?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) is a list of all permissions

Comment: Ok, thank you, any suggestions on the basic script I was loking for. The one supplied by @henrikpeinar didn't quite help med.

Comment: This is a really easy sdk https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk and has some simple examples

Comment: Ok, thank you, but where are the examnples? Do you mean the eaxmple.php-file. As I stated in my question, I've tried this script but it annoys med that I have to login before I'm asked for permissions. 
I just need to:
1. Autenticate
2. Ask for permissions

If you could help me with this I would be very thankful.

Comment: You should always logon to fb before you are asked for permissions. Who are you asking for permissions if you are not logged in?

Comment: Well, that's sort of my point, cause normally you are all ready logged on to Facebook when you want to try an application. You search for it or you are tipped by a friend. There's no need to logg in. And yet in the exampel provided by Facebook there's this logg in feature, whick make me think I've missed someting. I can ubderstand the need to logg in if you want to integrate with fb on your own site, but not if you are making an app on fb. Anyway, when i use the sdk-example I'm directed from the iframe back to the root url (where tha app is hosted) when I accept the permissions. U know why?

Comment: Yes, oauth redirects you back to you application and sends some tokens. The SDK (and so your application) uses these token to do other operations. The FB documentation is pretty good in describing oauth but you could also check the twitter or linkedin documentation since they too use oauth for the authenication part.

Answer (score 0):

try getting this url on some link or redirect the user to it:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?scope=email,user_about_me,publish_stream&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL&response_type=token

where the scope are the permission you are asking for, the clien_id sould be your app id (not the secret) and the redirect_uri (its URI not URL) is the site that the user will see after installing (I recomend to get here te full facebook app URL, i.e https://facebook.com/fanpage/?sk=app_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)

and thats the simpliest way, if you feel capable of more stuff you can use this PHP code:

```
$fbconfig['appid']     = "xxxyyy";
$fbconfig['secret']     = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$fbconfig['baseurl']    = "https://www.facebook.com/pages/FANPAGE/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?sk=xxxyyy";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
  'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
  'cookie' => true,
));

$user       = $facebook->getUser();

$loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
            'scope'         => 'email,user_about_me,publish_stream',
            'redirect_uri'  => $fbconfig['baseurl'],
            'display' => 'popup'
        )
);
```

and redirect user to the `$loginUrl`.

hope it helps, cheers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this piece of code did not fix the problem. When I load this nothing happens, literally. I included require 'src/facebook.php' at the top.