# Facebook PHP API "user hasn't authorized the application”

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

There is a similar question at: [Asking for permission using new PHP SDK (3.X.X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189151/asking-for-permission-using-new-php-sdk) but does not solves my problem.

My application is a Facebook Tab Application (Forum) which authorizes FB users to be able to post in the Forum. So far, so good. The authorization works fine. Now I want to extend a bit my application so user who subscribe to a thread, the app to be able to post on their timeline.

What I'm trying as test is:

```
    require_once('./includes/facebook.php');
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $CFG["appid"],
    'secret' => $CFG["appsecret"],
    'oauth' => true,
    'scope' => 'status_update,publish_stream,publish_actions',
    'cookie' => true
));
$facebookid = '';
$facebookid = $facebook->getUser();
if (!empty($facebookid))
{
    $facebook_info = array();
    $facebook_info=$facebook->api('/me');
    $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
                                array(
                                  'link' => 'www.example.com',
                                  'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!'
                             ));
```

}

But this gives error: Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action thrown in /home/facebook/public_html/demo/forum/includes/base_facebook.php on line 1271

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong? Please note that I tried to add the same permissions at the application settings (developers.facebook.com) but again I had no luck. For sure I'm missing something, but what's this?

Thank you

Comment: Have you already redirected the user to facebook so that they can accept permissions that are granted to your app?

Comment: wrap your code inside try {}catch(Exception $e){}

Comment: `scope`is not a parameter for the initialization of the SDK, it’s a parameter for the login flow. If you are not aware how that stuff works, please go read up on it in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

base_facebook.php, together with the code you'er using, makes me think that you're using the Facebook PHP-SDK library. `publish_stream` and `publish_actions` are now the same thing so you can skip that. `status_update` I've never seen. To post a status, you only need `publish_actions`.
Make sure you're using the updated library (they update it from time to time), which can be downloaded on github. That library gave me a similar error and I couldn't figure out the reason, so I have written my own authentication process, which isn't that complicated. 
For now, all that comes to my mind is that you have to check the permissions you ask, check if the user has authorized the app (that library does it with `getUser();`), and check that you have the latest version of the library.
If everything goes wrong, try with a simple auth url and debug by printing what you get from the API. Also, try to make sure that the callback url is always the same.
I hope this helps...